# What are other measures to consider when you don't have modification indices in your invariance test?

Tags: panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, mplus, invariance

I have a question considering longitudinal invariance testing.

The software I use is Mplus and I have tried three different scale application approaches; reference indicator approach, fixed factor approach and effects coding approach.

In Mplus, when implementing the effects coding approach, there is no way to get
modification indices when I use MODEL CONSTRAINTS: command to calculate
factor loadings and item intercepts (Mplus support told me so).
(My code looks like this in the MODEL CONSTRAINTS: section for Metric invariance)

```
MODEL CONSTRAINT:
  LLL1= 4 - LLL2 - LLL3 - LLL4;
  !T2L1= 4 - T2L2 - T2L3 - T2L4;
  !T3L1= 4 - T3L2 - T3L3 - T3L4;
  !T4L1= 4 - T4L2 - T4L3 - T4L4;
 

  !All mean model constraints are the same as configural model
  i1T1= 0 - i2T1 - i3T1 - i4T1;
  i1T2= 0 - i2T2 - i3T2 - i4T2;
  i1T3= 0 - i2T3 - i3T3 - i4T3;
  i1T4= 0 - i2T4 - i3T4 - i4T4;
```

That means, to my knowledge, I have only theory to back me up when I make decisions
of which parameter to free up.
Or, is there other information I could consider for making adjustments to the model?

Thank you so much for your support in advance.

Comment: Can you MODEL TEST: each constraint?

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my question. I have only experience in using MODEL TEST: for Wald tests and cannot come up with a way to figure out my issue. I would really appreciate it if you could elaborate on how exactly would you use it to specify where a lot of misfit is happening.

Comment: IIRC (it's a whlle since I've used Mplus) leave take one line out of MODEL CONSTRAINT: and add it to MODEL TEST:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when implementing the effects coding approach, there is no way to get modification indices when I use MODEL CONSTRAINTS:

Using `lavaan` in R, this is quite straight-forward using `lavTestScore()`.

Regardless of software, effects-coding makes it complicated to test 1 item at a time because even if you use different labels for one item (e.g., Item 4, with loading labeled `LLL4`), the constraint that the average of 4 loadings = 1 would imply the save value of the fourth loading across all 4 occasions.  The practical solution is to apply the effects-coding identification constraint to only the loadings that are held invariant (i.e., "anchor" items):

```
MODEL CONSTRAINT:
  LLL1= 3 - LLL2 - LLL3; ! 4th item omitted
```

Then you can define `NEW` parameters that represent DIF

```
difL_12 = T1L4 - T2L4;
difL_13 = T1L4 - T3L4;
difL_23 = T2L4 - T3L4;
...
```

Those user-defined DIF parameters each get their own 1-*df* Wald test.  But if you want a single omnibus Wald test, you can use `MODEL TEST` to test the set of constraints:

```
MODEL TEST:
  T1L4 = T2L4; ! this test has df=3, so
  T1L4 = T3L4; ! all 6 pairwise equalities
  T1L4 = T4L4; ! are implied by these 3
```

> there other information I could consider for making adjustments to the model?

The problem with this DIF-searching method is the inflated Type I error rate for non-DIF items that are tested when using DIF items as anchors. This is still a useful method for empirically choosing anchor items, though.  After testing each item (while each test assumes the other 3 are DIF-free), you can take the 50% of items with the smallest test statistics to treat as anchors. Then you fit the partial-invariance model and calculate Wald tests for the other 50% of items.  Because the empirically chosen anchor items are much less likely to include DIF (any Type I errors are probably a small effect size, so limited contamination), the Wald tests of other items tend to have very little bias or Type I error inflation.

This 2-step method (first select anchors, then test DIF) was first proposed for multigroup IRT models:

https://doi.org/10.1177/0146621607314044

But the general idea works just as well for multigroup or multioccasion CFA or MIMIC models:

https://doi.org/10.3758/s13428-018-1151-3

Comment: Wow! Thank you for your very detailed answer, Dr. Terrence!! I kind of follow the reasoning about how it is not a simple question of "freeing one parameter" for testing invariance in effects coding but the rest I need to chew on it for longer to really get your teaching. Nevertheless, you opened a new door for me to explore and I really appreciate it. Thanks again!!